# How can I interpret a P value of 3.1E-08?

Tags: statistical-significance

I used T test paired two samples for mean for comparing 2 groups of data (pre and post in the same population) and got this results. What does it mean. I am trying to figure out if the 2 data samples are different, statistically significant

Comment: There are many duplicates (with different specific numbers but the same scientific-notation/ e-notation) on site. Essentially all computers and almost all calculators use this notation to denote very small or very large numbers; you would normally encounter this notation in school, very soon after calculators start to be used. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E_notation